# Chart.js Date and Time Bar Chart Not Rendering - Line Works Though

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, chart.js2

I'm using Chart.js to create a datetime bar chart showing the number of players in multiple servers depending on the date and time of the last scan.  However, for some reason, the bar chart will not render.  If I use a line type chart, it renders just fine.  Anyone know why the bar chart will not render?  I don't have any console errors in developer tools.

Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/j3rmjzpw/2/

HTML:

```
<canvas id='playerChartLine' width='800' height='400'></canvas>
<canvas id='playerChartBar' width='800' height='400'></canvas>
```

Javascript / jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    renderChartJS("line", "playerChartLine", [{x: "2017-07-04T01:51:02-06:00", y: 240}, {x: "2017-07-04T10:51:02-06:00", y: 150}], "Total Number of Players Playing", "Date", "Players", "188,4,0", 0); // Number of players
    renderChartJS("bar", "playerChartBar", [{x: "2017-07-04T01:51:02-06:00", y: 240}, {x: "2017-07-04T10:51:02-06:00", y: 150}], "Total Number of Players Playing", "Date", "Players", "188,4,0", 0); // Number of players
});


function renderChartJS(chartType, elemId, data, title, xAxisLabel, yAxisLabel, rgbaColorStr, yMax){

    var ticksObj = {
        suggestedMin: 0,
        beginAtZero: true,   
        stepValue: 50,          
    }

    if(yMax != 0){
        ticksObj.max = yMax;
    }

    if(data.length){
        var ctx = document.getElementById(elemId).getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: chartType,
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    label: yAxisLabel,
                    data: data,
                    borderColor: "rgba(" + rgbaColorStr + ",1)",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(" + rgbaColorStr + ",0.5)"
                }],
            },
            options: {
                responsive: false,
                maintainAspectRatio: true,
                scaleBeginAtZero: true,
                title:
                {
                    display: true,
                    text: title
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        type: "time",
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: xAxisLabel
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            minRotation: 90,
                            maxRotation: 90,
                            stepValue: 10,
                            autoSkip: true,
                            maxTicksLimit: 50
                        },
                        time: {
                            unit: 'minute',
                            unitStepSize: 10,
                            max: data[data.length - 1].x
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: yAxisLabel
                        },
                        ticks: ticksObj
                    }]
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

The bottom chart should be the bar chart, but it is not rendering properly.

Anyone know what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is, bar chart doesn't support the type of data format, that you are providing.

You should rather use the following type of data format ...

```
renderChartJS("line", "playerChartLine", ["2017-07-04T01:51:02-06:00", "2017-07-04T10:51:02-06:00"], [240, 150], "Total Number of Players Playing", "Date", "Players", "188,4,0", 0); // Number of players
renderChartJS("bar", "playerChartBar", ["2017-07-04T01:51:02-06:00", "2017-07-04T01:59:02-06:00"], [240, 150], "Total Number of Players Playing", "Date", "Players", "188,4,0", 0); // Number of players
```

here, third argument is for x-axis `labels` and the forth one is for `data`

and, here's the working version of your code, with this applied ...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   renderChartJS("line", "playerChartLine", ["2017-07-04T01:51:02-06:00", "2017-07-04T10:51:02-06:00"], [240, 150], "Total Number of Players Playing", "Date", "Players", "188,4,0", 0); // Number of players
   renderChartJS("bar", "playerChartBar", ["2017-07-04T01:51:02-06:00", "2017-07-04T01:59:02-06:00"], [240, 150], "Total Number of Players Playing", "Date", "Players", "188,4,0", 0); // Number of players
});

function renderChartJS(chartType, elemId, labels, data, title, xAxisLabel, yAxisLabel, rgbaColorStr, yMax) {

   var ticksObj = {
      suggestedMin: 0,
      beginAtZero: true,
      stepValue: 50,
   }

   if (yMax != 0) {
      ticksObj.max = yMax;
   }

   if (data.length) {
      var ctx = document.getElementById(elemId).getContext('2d');
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
         type: chartType,
         data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
               label: yAxisLabel,
               data: data,
               borderColor: "rgba(" + rgbaColorStr + ",1)",
               backgroundColor: "rgba(" + rgbaColorStr + ",0.5)"
            }],
         },
         options: {
            responsive: false,
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            scaleBeginAtZero: true,
            title: {
               display: true,
               text: title
            },
            scales: {
               xAxes: [{
                  type: "time",
                  display: true,
                  scaleLabel: {
                     display: true,
                     labelString: xAxisLabel
                  },
                  ticks: {
                     minRotation: 90,
                     maxRotation: 90,
                     stepValue: 10,
                     autoSkip: true,
                     maxTicksLimit: 50
                  },
                  time: {
                     unit: 'minute',
                     unitStepSize: 10,
                     max: data[data.length - 1].x
                  }
               }],
               yAxes: [{
                  display: true,
                  scaleLabel: {
                     display: true,
                     labelString: yAxisLabel
                  },
                  ticks: ticksObj
               }]
            }

         }
      });
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/download/v2.6.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id='playerChartLine' width='800' height='400'></canvas>
<canvas id='playerChartBar' width='800' height='400'></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think Chart.js would be better if you don't have to change the data format based on the type of chart rendered.  I'll see what they say on GitHub.

Comment: I had a similar experience as @OwN, couldn't get a bar chart to work until I split up the data and labels into separate arrays.  

However [the documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#data-structure) implies that the `{x, y}`-styled data works with bar charts.  Any thoughts as to what the problem is?  Bad documentation?

Comment: @David Peters `{x, y}` data style has been implemented in ChartJS v2.7 onwards, so you should switch to the new version if you're using an old one.